# Array to multiple object in underscore

Tags: arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{
    LocalBond:"0",
    LocalCash:"2.42",
    LocalEquity:"0",
    ForeignEquity: "4",
    ...
}]
```

What I want it look like:

```
[{
    Source: "LocalBond",
    Value: "0"
},
    Source: "LocalCash",
    Value: "2.42"
},
    Source: "LocalEquity",
    Value: "0"
},
{...}
]
```

I want to turn a single object into many objects.  I also need the exclude the *'ForeignEquity'* result.

I tried using `_.map`, and returning the fields I want, but I am struggling a bit.  Am I on the right track?  When I pass more than one parameter into my function, I don't get the desired result.

Comment: really the init array have a one object, or more objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple code is pure javascript:

Using for..in access to the property of the object, and inside of the for loop build the array.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/jewrsL8a/5/

```
var collection = [{
    LocalBond:"0",
    LocalCash:"2.42",
    LocalEquity:"0",
    ForeignEquity: "4"
}];

var result = [];

for (var property in collection[0]) {
    if(property!=='ForeignEquity'){
      result.push({'Source': property, 'Value': collection[0][property]});
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: 'Value' in this case should be collection[0][property]

Comment: let is not supportted well in some browsers

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that I do not really want to do an IF Statement excluding 20 odd values. Same goes for including.  Trying to figure a way around.  The IF statement is last resort.

Comment: Thanks @allel for your answer.  It gave me an idea.  I did eventually end up using underscore.  For the part about excluding values, I used underscores .contains filter and pushed the remaining values to an array.  Worked perfectly!

Comment: @jae.phoenix you could also use underscore's `pick` or `omit` to select the keys you want